# How do I check the data corruption after compressing my file in Python?

Tags: python, zip, compression, md5, checksum

Let's suppose that we have `/tmp/photos/essay.gz`.
And, I decompressed the file and got `essay.txt`.
Then, I re-compressed the `essay.txt` to `essay.zip`.

The problem is, how do I verify that the data is not corrupted?
My shot was to decompress the `essay.zip` and compare the md5 checksum of those two `essay.txt` files. And, am I checking the file corruption correctly?

The other problem that came up to my mind was, how do we even know that the decompression from `essay.gz` was not corrupted?

If there are more efficient ways that I can do, please suggest any of them (with sample codes will be really appreciated!)

Comment: While file formats do sometimes have checksums (especially when network transport and other machines are involved), why do you suppose that the simple act of decompression needs checking any more than any other I/O?

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for the comment. I am new to work on this concept. Would you elaborate more on your explanation or suggest me any related reference materials?